# ObjectCache.AddOrGetExisting - what is this method for? Is it completely useless?

Tags: .net, caching

First of all, I know what does [ObjectCache.AddOrGetExisting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ee395901.aspx) do (System.Runtime.Caching namespace). My question is **why** does it exist?

Here it this method's declaration:

```
public override Object AddOrGetExisting(
    string key,
    Object value,
    CacheItemPolicy policy,
    string regionName
)
```

What confuses me is the parameter "value". **If I had a value ready on each call, I wouldn't need cache - I would just use the newest value and not the one from cache**!

The only usage I could imagine is supplying Lazy as value. But if this is the only useful usage, why not just receive `Func<object> valueProvider` as a parameter?

**PS:** Actually the whole API of the ObjectCache looks more like a Dictionary than a ready-to-use cache. And to use it I must create a wrapper and write a lot of additional logic, including synchronization (and I say many similar implementations to adopt cache for normal usage) - that's not what I would expect from BCL Cache implementation. Is it only my concern?

Comment: Looks like you're not alone: http://dougwork.blogspot.com/2012/10/objectcache-in-net-4.html